# I cant get my graphics to work properly

Tags: intel-graphics

my Ubuntu 12.04.04 cant boot unless i use the nomodeset parameter at boot time.
but that way vesa drivers are loaded and my resolution is lower than expected.

I have an Intel Sandy Bridge processor with integrated graphics

Comment: i have pretty same  graphic cards and yes when I was on ubuntu 12.04 i needed nomodeset, 12.10 never worked, xubuntu 13.10 worked great, now  I'm on xubuntu 14.04 beta, and it's working great too

Answer (score 0):

System specs and installed programs/drivers relevant to your situation would go a long way in helping anyone diagnose the problem.

Comment: could you please tell me which commands you want me to execute in order to give you system specs ?